# Which is better to build the database inside android or on a server?

Tags: android, database

I'm building an application to check RFID tag using NFC. And I'm not really an expert in android. However , which would be better
If I build the database in Android using SQLiteDatabase or I build the database on a server using MySQL and PHP!
One more question, if I used SQLiteDatabase can I sync it on a server?

I'm doing this for my final year project. I don't want solutions.  All what I want is someone to guide me which way is better.

Answer (score 2):

In short: "it depends". There are couple of things to consider:

- Latency, if you need answers quickly probably store it locally.
- Remote dependencies, if you need to contact other services before returning it might be good to use a server and some form of cache.
- Size, if your database is small you can store it locally, if it's big probably store it on a server.
- Other factors to consider.

As for myself I use a small database on the phone and retrieve only the necessary parts of the big database stored in the server, sync on demand. I wrote the server in django but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: My database isn't large but by the end of the day I need to sync it with a server using internet. I think sync on demand is the best way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every solution has pros and cons. If you're speaking about database of tags, then the question is how big it's going to be and how often are you going to update it. If you use local database then you don't need internet connection. I would use mixture of both, meaning store data in local database and do requests to remote one, when id was not found locally.

Comment: I think it is the best way to do it. Thank you